# How to use Firebase Auth to register/login/mint token but Mongodb for everything else?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, firebase-authentication

--First time poster, mods please let me know if the question is inappropriate/incorrect--

**Situation:**

I'm working on an app with friends. We have a dedicated frontend layer and a dedicated nodejs server running MongoDB. I am trying to integrate firebase into our server layer so we can login users and handle minting/verifying/refreshing tokens using Firebase Auth.

**Problem:**

I'm completely lost as to how to use Firebase Auth for this purpose. I've looked through the docs extensively, I first went down the "Getting Started with Firebase on an App", until I realized (I think) that guide was specifically for web applications without a dedicated backend.

Then I looked more into Firebase Auth Admin, which looked more like what I was looking for. I tried messing with custom token creation and other authentication related matters but I fail to be able to log in.

I reached out to friends for help, they recommended getting local login/googleauth working End-to-end using firebase before trying to secure our tokens moreso than they already are.

I'm very lost and not sure if I'm misunderstanding something fundamental or just not applying the right things. I apologize if this is unclear, I'm just trying to **allow email/password login using firebase auth to securely authenticate with my MongoDB data (if that's even necessary)**

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right with your approach and its possible to use Firebase Auth for just login/signup and rest of all on mongoDB.

There are 2 ways u can implement the Firebase Auth-

1. Using the sdk provided by Firebase
2. Using the [Admin Auth API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin)

Which ever way you selected, Later on save your UID on your custom Backend (Which is backed by MongoDB)

Just create your API's to verify user identity.

If you're using NodeJs you can follow this [tutorial.](https://dev.to/emeka/securing-your-express-node-js-api-with-firebase-auth-4b5f)